# Property text not found on object

Tags: objective-c, compiler-errors, label

I am a bit new to Xcode and Parse and am creating a query in a outlet collection. Everything looks fine except I am getting an error stating "Property 'text' not found on object of type 'id'"... Here is my code that I have:

```
[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
    if (!error) {
        // The find succeeded.
        NSLog(@"Successfully retrieved %d scores.", objects.count);
        // Do something with the found objects
        int i = 0;
        for (PFObject *object in objects) {
            if (i >= [self.EventTitles count]) break;//to make sure we only write up to the max number of UILabels available in EventTitles
            (UILabel *) self.EventTitles[i].text = object.objectId;//I assume the "objectId" property of object is an NSString!
            i++;
        }
    } else {
        // Log details of the failure
        NSLog(@"Error: %@ %@", error, [error userInfo]);
    }
}];
```

Can anyone help me so I can get this build to not fail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this:

```
(UILabel *) self.EventTitles[i].text = object.objectId;
```

to:

```
[(UILabel *)self.EventTitles[i] setText:object.objectId];
```